# Postalcode for multiple countries

Tags: geocoding, tableau-api, postal-code

Having a column that mixes German (5 digits) and Austrian (4 digits) postal codes. How can I make Tableau understand both correctly?

The column reads something like

```
postal-code
53173
99848
1080
1030
```

I assigned a geo-role to a second column that distinguishes the countries:

```
country-code
DE
DE
AT
AT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the data that you provided and I had no issue with Tableau recognizing them correctly.

You may need to specifically set the `Geographic role` for each field, but that should be it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What Nicarus said.

With this data:

```
postal-code country-code
53173       DE
99848       DE
1080        AT
1030        AT
```

You can do this (just make sure to change the geographic role for the postal code as shown below):

[image]